# Bad Rendering in Ubuntu (not bad font rendering)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, google-chrome, fonts

It is weird that after the first time I lock the Ubuntu screen and then I open it, the screen rendering looks terrible and the screen does not update. I also have awful rendering in Chrome and other apps, like Slack.

First I searched and only found "bad rendering" about fonts, but my case is not like this bad font rendering that people mention.

First I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and then I thought that the problem is due to the version, so I then updated it to 18.04. I again had the same problem. Now I have installed 20.04.

My graphics driver is an NVIDIA GP107M or GTX 1050 Titan. I first installed the NVIDIA version 450 driver and I thought that the problem is from the driver, but I test all driver versions and the problem still persists.

Below are some pictures that may help you understand more:

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

[image: picture3]

My specs are the following:

- Laptop model: Acer Nitro 5 AN515
- CPU: Core i7 7700hq
- RAM: 16 GB
- swap: 12 GB
- root space: 128 GB SSD
- home space: 1 TB HDD
- monitor:  Full HD - 1920×1080

Anyway, thanks for your help and sorry for my bad writing.
writing

Comment: Can you clarify this: Is this happening only in Chrome or any other applications (like LibreOffice)? Give some examples of other application exhibiting the same problem.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli
yes i update and add a new picture(picture3). slack application.
in fact this is happening in all application.

Comment: Can you provide more details about hardware and software? Which version of Ubuntu? What kind of computer, graphics card and monitor(s) are you using?

Comment: @Joe yes actually i update it again and put this detail in it.
sorry about it , i don't know what can be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

After a bit, I found out that because of updating from ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04, my desktop environment was Unity, and it has some conflict with my driver that I don't know. After I changed it to Gnome, everything worked correctly.